# Purpose of Splitting Fields

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I understand that the splitting field for a given polynomial is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ for which the polynomial factors linearly. But if we know that every polynomial splits over $\mathbb{C}$, what is the purpose of finding the smallest field for which it splits?

Comment: For example, we might want to do Galois theory to that field.

Comment: For example the characteristic might be $\ne 0$. Or even in characteristic $0$ the base field might already be much larger than $\Bbb C$.

Comment: This is not long enough to be an answer, but mainly I think it's that $\mathbb{C}$ is big, and we want to ignore all the other parts of $\mathbb{C}$ that aren't relevant to the polynomial(s) in question. And as Qiaochu Yuan points out, taking a small field lets us apply the results of Galois Theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you please demonstrate with an example or provide one (that I can make sense of myself)?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense unless you say what base field you have in mind.